# Как подключиться к Интернету в Linux Puppy?

Tags: linux

Как подключиться к Интернету в Linux Puppy?

Компьютер подключён к кабельной виртуальной частной сети через плату Ethernet. Провайдером заданы логин, пароль и адрес pptp.xxxxx.ru, который при работе в Windows XP вводиться в строку "Имя компьютера" Мастера подключения.

В Puppy пытался установить подключение с помощью "Мастера подключения к Интернет". В Мастере подключения сообщение: "Найден сетевой интерфейс eth0". Пытался подключится через опции "локальная проводная сеть" и "VPN соединение через gpptp...", но безрезультатно.

В первом случае значёк в трее показал установку соединения,но негде указать логин и пароль. Во втором случае в строке "VPN сервер" указал адрес pptp.xxxxx.ru и далее логин и пароль; в результате получил сообщение: "pptp process was NOT created!..." и т. д.

Прошу совета! Юрий Тереш.

Answer (score 1):

1. NetworkManager  используется?
2. если "да", то идем в настройки соединений (в трее висит значек подключения > ПраваяКнопаМыши > изменить соединения);
3. переходим на вкладку VPN и говорим "Добавить" , далее в окошке выбираем тип подключения: "Point-to-point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP)" , жмем "Создать";
4. В новом окне настраиваем параметры соединения. При этом шлюз=pptp.provider.ru, ну и так далее - логин, пароль и т.п.

Естественно, перед этим у Вас должно быть подключение к сети провайдера (имеется ввиду т.н. "локалка").

Если описанных выше пунктов нет - следовательно, некоторые аддоны к NM у Вас не установлены - установить можно с диска. Но обычно с комплекте с NM они устанавливаются.

По большому счету, все так же как и в винде: сначала устанавливаем соединение с локальной сетью прова, а уж потом, поверх него, соединение VPN (т.е. выход в интернет через локалку провайдера).